# add image to div in code behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, html, .net-3.5

Is there any way to add an image that is loaded from db to a div that already exist in aspx file e.g. if I have the following :

```
<div id="dp" class="red">
</div>
```

I cannot use runat=server as my jquery breaks. so I was thinking to somehow find this div and append to it the image.

is this possible, can someone please guide me.

**EDIT :**

little more info :

So I added a hidden value in aspx file and whenever im loading the page i assign the image in foreach loop.

In my jquery i managed to get the value using

```
alert($("input[id$=imageval1]").val());
```

now is there a way to append this to my div above

Comment: you can't reference an element in code behind without specifying runat=server.  what exactly do you mean by "jquery breaks"?

Comment: I think he meant that if you do `runat="server"` the .net framework changes the id of the runat=server element, according to that, jquery cant find the element `#dp`

Comment: `runat="server"` won't break your jQuery. All it does is tell your server how to find the element. If it's changing the ID on the clientside, then you need to use clientID `var myDiv = '<%=dp.ClientId %>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with jQuery.  This adds the `<img/>` as the last child inside `#dp` with class `red`.

```
$('<img src="' + $("input[id$=imageval1]").val() + '" width="" height="" alt="" />').appendTo( $("#dp.red") );
```

Here's the full JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('<img src="' + $("input[id$=imageval1]").val() + '" width="" height="" alt="" />').appendTo( $("#dp.red") );
});
</script>
```

Code edited to reflect OP's edit.

Comment: @Timothy, agreed. Just never know what OP's coding practices are :}

Comment: @SetSailMedia check my edit please would i be able to append hidden field ?

Comment: @Sam What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
<div id="dp" class="red">
    <img id="myImage" runat="server" />
</div>
```

In your C# code just add your image src to the "myImage" element...

Comment: OP has to add images from Code behind.

Comment: He meant on the div.. not on the image... see my second comment on the question

Answer (score 1):

You jQuery breaks which means the events are not attaching the right way when adding `runat="server"` because asp.net put a dynamic id instead of the id you put.
If you are using asp.net 4.0 you can solve that by making the `ClientIDMode = static` and like that the id will keep the same and asp.net will not edit it.

```
<div id="dp" class="red" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static">
</div>
```

[Good article about ClientIDMode](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40)

Comment: because he had a problem with it, and I listed a solution for that.

Comment: @Sam1 I'm pretty sure it's not available in 3.5. Check out my answer on how to get around the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(function(){ $('#dp').append('<img src="insertURLhere" />'); });`

Comment: If the DIV already exists when the script is run, you won't need the wrapping `$(document).ready( function(){  });` function; if you're not sure, just leave it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all with code, and it'll work without javascript.

**View**

```
<div id="dp" class="red" runat="server">
</div>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
dp.innerHtml = @"<img src=""myimage.png"" />";
```

Also, if you need to access the div that has `runat="server"` attached to it with javascript, you will be able to do so by using `ClientID`

```
var myDiv = '<%=dp.ClientId %>';
```

Comment: only because he felt it broke his jquery. I posted a solution as to NOT break the javascript.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell: but whenever i use the runat it breaks jquery...I have drag and drop image and that will not work

Comment: Did you try referencing the element using `'<%=dp.ClientId %>';`? What's probably happening is that the .NET framework is changing your element ID at runtime. getting the `ClientID` is how you are able to find the element in the DOM.

Comment: Java script is already fine his side, issue is in design only when RunAt server is used.

Comment: @PankajGarg it's just one option. There are many ways to [skin a cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:MartinHarper/cat_skinning), the OP just has to choose one and go with it. I'm not here for a debat. Personally I hate webforms and prefer to do all of this in MVC with HTML Helpers.

Comment: Then you are wasting your time for wrong tags and the answer you gave is not even approximate to the exact answer.

Comment: +1, since he is not using asp.net 4.0 so i see this is the best answer.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell he has already mentioned that he cant use runat="server" and according to him his jquery code will break..!

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE, if the jQuery breaks, it's a deeper problem. Fix it so jQuery doesn't break. This *is* how you do it in WebForms... MVC is a different matter.

Comment: `runat="server"` won't break jQuery. All it does is tell the server how to find the element. If it's changing the ID on the clientside, then you need to use clientID var myDiv = '<%=dp.ClientId %>';

Answer (score -1):

> You need **[DataList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.aspx)**. Set your `Display Direction` and `Layout`
>   using Datalist control.

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="dp" class="red">
    <asp:DataList ID="DDl" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("Images") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
```

---

**Code Behind**

```
using (DataTable DT = new DataTable())
{
    using (DataColumn DC = new DataColumn("Images"))
    {
        DT.Columns.Add(DC);
        DataRow DR = DT.NewRow();
        DR["Images"] = "Chrysanthemum.jpg";
        DT.Rows.Add(DR);

        DR = DT.NewRow();
        DR["Images"] = "Hydrangeas.jpg";
        DT.Rows.Add(DR);

        DR = DT.NewRow();
        DR["Images"] = "Hydrangeas.jpg";
        DT.Rows.Add(DR);

        DDl.DataSource = DT;
        DDl.DataBind();
    }
}
```